# MongoDB : Single update on multiple fields V/S Multiple updates on single field?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, updates

I have a collection which has 7 arrays, and each array contains more than 1000 subdocuments.
i.e.

```
{  
    "_id": 1,
    "arr1": [
        { "date": 20100101, "time": 120000, "key": "value1" },
        { "date": 20100401, "time": 121500, "key": "value2" },
        ...
        { "date": 20161001, "time": 120000, "key": "valueN" },
    ],
    .
    .
    "arr7": [
        { "date": 20100101, "time": 120000, "key": "value1" },
        { "date": 20100401, "time": 121500, "key": "value2" },
        ...
        { "date": 20161001, "time": 120000, "key": "valueN" },
    ]
}
```

I want to pull activities that are older than a particular date from all the arrays. 
Should i execute a single update which will pull matching sub-documents from each array at once, i.e.

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, { $pull: { arr1: { date: { $lt: 151031 } }, arr2: { date: { $lt: 151031 } }, ... arr7: { date: { $lt: 151031 } } } })
```

Or should i execute update separately for each array. i.e.

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, { $pull: { arr1: { date: { $lt: 20160101 } } } })
db.collection.updateMany({}, { $pull: { arr2: { date: { $lt: 20160101 } } } })
...
db.collection.updateMany({}, { $pull: { arr7: { date: { $lt: 20160101 } } } })
```

Which would be more effective ?

Comment: So you have only one document with 7 arrays in your collection? If yes your data design is really bad. Earlier or later you will run into the 16MB-per-document limitation of mongo...

Comment: No, i have around 3200000 such documents and each of them having such 7 arrays. This arrays are increasing in size along with time. And i want to remove old sub-documents from arrays and keeping only that data which is relevant to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you should use a single query to pull from all the arrays

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, { $pull: { arr1: { date: { $lt: 151031 } }, arr2: { date: { $lt: 151031 } }, ... arr7: { date: { $lt: 151031 } } } })
```

This gives the mongo query optimizer full control of the execution. For example it may have to access each object only once and not seven times.

You should look at the exact execution of the query using `explain()` though (see https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.explain/).

You also may want to consider changing your data model as you might get into problems with mongo 16MB per document restriction. Also array indexes in mongo are very inefficient with such huge arrays.